# Compress and Upload vis SSH?

Tags: compression, remote, archiving, upload, godaddy

Is it possible to compress several folders and upload to another location (ftp) remotely?

I've a GoDaddy account with SSH access, and I'd like to create a backup (zip all folders) and upload directly from GoDaddy to my new host FTP, is it possible? Can you please provide the commands for those operations?

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of ways to go about this, but here's a general example:

Compress the public_html directory, or whichever folder contains your site:

```
tar czvf site.tar.gz public_html/
```

login to the remote FTP server (Login process may differ depending on software used - host and credentials will change obviously, swap localhost with your remote ftp server):

```
ftp localhost
Name (localhost:john): john
331 User john okay, need password.
Password:
KERBEROS_V4 set as authentication type
230-You are user #12 of 50 simultaneous users allowed.
```

upload your files:

```
put site.tar.gz
```

log out of the FTP server:

```
bye
```

Comment: It would be a lot better to use `sftp` for this, if you care about neighbours armed with `tcpdump`.